# Predict class having only class proportions for every attribute (non labeled data)

Tags: classification, data-mining, predictive-modeling, probability, scoring

I am working with a big data set (millions of observations) where for each observation I am trying to predict a probability (or score it) of being of a class. I haven't any labeled training data and it is impossible to collect it.

So far I found a service that allows to query several times per hour with min amount of allowed observations starting from several thousands and with no upper boundary, ultimately service returns the proportion of the class for each tested group of observations. I assume here that an observation with a target class is more likely to appear in corresponding groups, and I would like to preserve this assumtion here, as without it the idea doesn't make any sense.

Data can be non-randomly grouped into multiple slices by attributes where some of attributes has quite good positive or negative relationship with the class.

way to think about it:

```
| observation_id  | attr1 | attr2 | attr3 | … | attrN |
|-----------------|-------|-------|-------|---|-------|
| _1              | 1     | 0     | 1     | … | 0     |
| _2              | 0     | 0     | 1     | … | 1     |
| _3              | 0     | 0     | 1     | … | 0     |
| _4              | 1     | 0     | 1     | … | 1     |
| _5              | 1     | 0     | 0     | … | 0     |
| _6              | 1     | 0     | 0     | … | 1     |
| …               | …     | …     | …     | … | …     |
| M               | 1     | 0     | 1     | … | 0     |


If I group observations by attrs I receive sets of a different cardinality of observation and I can gather such info:
```

attr1 = {_1,_4,_5,_6,...,M} and has 73% proportion of a target class

attr3 = {_1,_2,_3,_4,...,M} and has 46% proportion of a target class

...

attrN = {has some observations} and has some proportion of a class

So it turns out that any observation is a member of a group with a known probability (proportion) to have a target class if you pick one observation at random. The objective is to find a way to infer which observation relates to a target class from from class proportion for every observation given knowledge of the class proportion for every group.

Is there any model type or scoring approach to optimise this process to infer the likelihood of observation being of the class from knowing the proportion of the class in multiple groups where this observation lives? By optimisation I mostly mean minimisation of testing iterations as it takes quite a lot of time, and if possible gaining more information from lower amount of features (in this case - affinity to a group by attribute).

Any hint or reference to an article/book/page will be super helpful :) Thanks a lot!

Comment: In general classification algorithms require a target class to train on to then predict and outcome. Without one, you cannot really classify your data. You can certainly cluster your data (deciding how many clusters create) which would sort out your data into groups most like each other....you could create labels from there and then classify future data against those cluster labels....but true classification is supervised, and supervised learning requires a class definition.

Comment: Nice question. I wonder if any of the parts is tractable without some very specific assumptions. I would try to estimate probabilities for disjoint bins of indices. I think you can get around the minimum restriction by requesting the bin you want padded with a set of random indices where the probability will be roughly the same.